# Trying to get ReactJS to draw image on canvas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

I'm working on a game using ReactJS and Electron. I have a React Component that I want to load my gamemap on (it's a 2d tileset map). To do that, I pass the component the name of the directory I want to load the resources from. Once it reads in the game.json file, it knows where to look for the map tileset data.
Once it loads the tileset data, I want it to calculate the tiles sprites and place them in the appropriate areas.

My issues are the following:

1. Does it make sense to place this functionality in the componentWillMount() function?
2. Does asynchronicity have anything to do with the Image file not being loaded properly?
3. Assuming everything checks out, why can't the canvas draw the image I'm passing it?

Looking at the data, the sx/sy/dx/dy coordinates are all where I want them to be. Uncommenting out the componentDidMount() function shows that getting the image file results in ../path/null in the console.

Any suggestions?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Map extends React.Component{
    //Set all vars to null
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            mapArr:     [],
            directory:  null,
            data:       null,
            players:    null,
            enemies:    null,
            objective:  null,
            map:        null,
            tileset:    null
        }
    }

    // Given this.props.gamemap, load the game.json file that it points to
    // Given the game.json, set the path to the map it references
    componentWillMount(){
        //Process game data
        this.directory = this.props.gamemap;
        this.data = require('./content/' + this.directory + '/game.json');
        this.players = this.data.players;             //Players
        this.enemies = this.data.enemies;             //Enemies
        this.objective = this.data.objective;         //Game Objective
        this.map = this.data.map;                     //Map name

        this.setState({
            data:       this.data,
            players:    this.players,
            enemies:    this.enemies,
            objective:  this.objective,
        });

        // Read in map data
        let _this = this;
        axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: './content/' + _this.directory + '/' + _this.map,
            responseType: 'text',
            timeout:1000
        })
        .then(function(response){
            // console.log(response.data);
            var tileSize = 16;
            var mapData = response.data.split("\n");
            var mapArr = [];
            var tileset = "";
            var mapWidthTiles = 0;
            var mapHeightTiles = 0;
            var mapWidthPX = 0;
            var mapHeightPX = 0;

            var acc = 0;
            var line;
            for(line in mapData){
                if(acc === 0)
                    tileset = './content/' + _this.directory + '/' + mapData[line] + '.png';
                else if(acc === 1){
                    mapWidthTiles = mapData[line].split(" ")[0];
                    mapHeightTiles = mapData[line].split(" ")[1];
                    mapWidthPX = mapWidthTiles * tileSize;
                    mapHeightPX = mapHeightTiles * tileSize;
                }
                else
                    mapArr.push(mapData[line].split(" "));
                acc++;
            }
            _this.setState({
                mapArr:         mapArr,
                mapWidthTiles:  mapWidthTiles,
                mapHeightTiles: mapHeightTiles,
                mapWidthPX:     mapWidthPX,
                mapHeightPX:    mapHeightPX,
                tileset:        tileset,
            });
        })
        .catch(function(error){
        });
    }

    componentDidMount(){
         this.paint();
    }

    componentDidUpdate(){
        this.paint();
    }
    //Paint Canvas with map data
    // * BUG HERE *
    paint(){
        var context = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.gameMap).getContext('2d');
        var tileSize = 16;
        this.mapArr = this.state.mapArr;
        this.tileset = this.state.tileset;
        this.image = new Image();
        this.image.src = this.tileset;

        //Given a map and a tileset location, we can now render the map
        //  mapArr[x][y] = val
        //  val divided by 32 (whole int) = y
        //  remainder = x
        let _this = this;
        if(this.image.complete){
            console.log("Image complete");
            for(var dx=0 ; dx<_this.mapArr.length ; dx++){
                for(var dy=0 ; dy<_this.mapArr[dx].length ; dy++){
                    var sy = Math.floor(_this.mapArr[dx][dy]/32);
                    var sx = _this.mapArr[dx][dy]%32;
                    context.drawImage(
                        _this.image,
                        sx*this.tileSize, sy*this.tileSize, this.tileSize, this.tileSize,
                        dx*this.tileSize, dy*this.tileSize, this.tileSize, this.tileSize);
                }
            }       
        }
        else{
            this.image.onload = function(){
                console.log("Image loaded");
                for(var dx=0 ; dx<_this.mapArr.length ; dx++){
                    for(var dy=0 ; dy<_this.mapArr[dx].length ; dy++){
                        var sy = Math.floor(_this.mapArr[dx][dy]/32);
                        var sx = _this.mapArr[dx][dy]%32;
                        context.drawImage(
                            _this.image,
                            sx*this.tileSize, sy*this.tileSize, this.tileSize, this.tileSize,
                            dx*this.tileSize, dy*this.tileSize, this.tileSize, this.tileSize);
                    }
                }       
            }
            this.image.onerror = function(res){
                console.log("Could not load game map");
                console.log(res);
            }
        }
    }

    render(){
        return <canvas 
                id="map"
                ref="gameMap"
                width={this.state.mapWidthPX} 
                height={this.state.mapHeightPX}/>            
    }
}
```

Comment: You should check out [Fliboard](https://github.com/Flipboard/react-canvas) if you haven't already. Creates a canvas React wrapper that makes it much nicer to work with.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda I looked into react-canvas, but it does not suit my needs at this time. (Unless I missed something in their documentation)

I don't want to paint a whole image. I have an image (a tileset) that I want to load specific sprite (sub-images so to speak) and place it in a specific section of the canvas.

If react-canvas has that functionality/api handy, that'd be great. Otherwise, I have to rely on canvas.drawImage().